# Server 2016 - Storage HD & "Server Folders" missing even though can access shares

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am getting a warning about missing `Server Folders` in the `Windows Server Essentials Dashboard`.

The Server Folders on a RAID drive used for filesharing are marked `missing` in the `>Dashboard >Storage >Server Folders`. Also the drive R:\ (an intel RST software Raid1 made from 2 physical harddrives is not listed any longer in `>Dashboard >Storage >Hard Drives`

The Raid drive R:\ is present though.

1. I can see it in the File Explorer
2. users can access it's shared folders
3. the `Rapid Storage Technology` interface tells me: *"Your system is functioning normally"*.

I didn't realize in the first moment that the HD was reported missing and have accidentally `recreated` one of the Server Folders (which was unused and empty) as suggested by the Dashboard. This has created a new folder on a secondary harddrive `E:\`. So I'm wondering whether I can cut that false connection somehow, so there is no conflict once the actual drive is regognized again by the damn Dashboard.

This machine is the result of a migration process from a SBS 2008 and there are still some unsolved problems with DNS (the new server can not create users without the legacy SBS being onine i.e.) and so I'm wondering whether this may be related in any way? 5 fsmo roles are with the new server already though.

disclaimer: very new to Windows Server admin, so I may lack some basics :-(

Comment: I don't get where you are getting the names of the GUI parts from? I'm guessing you mean "Server Manager" when you say "Dashboard", but there is no "Storage" tab for it - but there is "File and Storage Services".. and under that there is no "Server Folders" either. Could this perhaps be Small Business Server? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: no, not the Server Manager @pauska. "Windows Server Essentials Dashboard" seems to be the complete name (sorry if I missed to mention the 'Essentials' part in my post). The OS in the meantime actually IS a 'Standard' Edition but somehow some "Essentials" features seem to be in play yet. And there IS a tab called Storage. in that Dashboard. I don't think the "Server Manager" has an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

seems that was just a hickup of the server. Without any obvious action from my part the `Server Folders`are listed in the "Windows Server Essentials Dashboard" anew. The Raid drive as well has reappeared in `>Dashboard >Storage >Hard Drives`.

I solved the problem mentioned to appear due to my faulty reconnecting of the (empty) Server Folder named 'Company' by renaming the (unconnected) folder `R:\Server Folders\Company` to `~\Company_to-be-removed`(I guess I also could have just deleted that just alike and then to right click on the Dashboard entry for the Server Folder `Company` and follow the instructions to "Move the folder"